# MySQL in_array function - Invalid second argument

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to determine whether or not the user has voted on a certain item and changing the image for the vote icon accordingly.

```
$user_likes = mysql_query("SELECT * from ratings WHERE userid = '$uid' AND aggregate = 1");
while ($row_likes = mysql_fetch_array($user_likes)) {
$row_likes['imageid'] = $likes_array;
}
```

Now in my content, I have a PHP foreach that returns a menu item for each submission (that is what users can vote on), the `$image['idnum']` is the ID value for that individual image. The 'ratings' table seen in the query above is where I store votes like this: user id, image id, aggregate (in this case 1, to represent a like). Here is the in_array function that is giving me trouble:

```
if (in_array($image['idnum'], $likes_array)) {
    echo 'vote_triangle.png';
}
```

I'm getting the following error message:

**Warning**:  in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in **(filename)** on line **33**

Comment: You are not passing an array as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have this part backwards:

```
while ($row_likes = mysql_fetch_array($user_likes)) {
    $row_likes['imageid'] = $likes_array; // ????
}
```

Should be:

```
// Initialize the array
$likes_array = array();

while ($row_likes = mysql_fetch_array($user_likes)) {
     $likes_array[] = $row_likes['imageid'];
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I had a feeling it would be something messed up with my array. I'll select your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Do you fully understand it? The first version makes no sense, looks like it was basically a typo or "dumb" mistake.

Comment: I'm a bit embarrassed, but MySQL arrays confuse the hell out of me. I do better understand why I needed the `[]` to determine that it's an array and then use it as such in the function. I just thought that the variable would have stored `$row_likes['imageid']` as an array.

Comment: `$row_likes` is reset in every iteration in the `while` loop, and `$likes_array` is undefined. I used `$likes_array = array();` in case we don't get any results from the database, you'd still have a valid (empty) array.

Comment: I didn't even notice the `array()` but that definitely makes more sense. Thanks again!